# Multiple relationships to the same SQLAlchemy model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `User` table that has `role` column. role can be `student`, `professor` or `admin`. User table have relation with `Course` table.

If relationship is between `Course` and  `student` it should be `many to many` relation but if relationship is between `Course` and  `professor` it should be `one to many`.

How to define multi relationship between two table with different roles?

**User Model**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(40))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(40))
    username = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, nullable=False, default=0)
    create_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    update_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)


    # what should i write instead of bellow lines?

    # courses = db.relationship('Course', secondary=student_course, backref='students', lazy='dynamic')

    # OR

    # courses = db.relationship('Course', backref='teacher', lazy='dynamic')
    ROLE_STUDENT = 0
    ROLE_PROFESSOR = 1
    ROLE_ADMIN = 2
```

**Course Model**

```
class Course(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    teacher_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120))
```

Comment: This feels a lot like a breach of the [1st normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Are you sure you want to overload the `User` table like this? Is there perhaps a better schema design to avoid trying to have a relationship that varies based on some other user attribute?